# Is there a way to set gridline options for Excel graphs using C# / EPPlus

Tags: c#, xml, excel, graph, epplus

I am trying to create an excel Graph using EPPlus and C#.   I can successfully create the following Graph:
[image: Graph Created]
However, I would like the program to create both major and minor gridlines in both directions at runtime; so that the graph looks like this:
[image: Graph Desired]

I know I can adjust these settings in Excel, but I would like to be able to set the default gridlines with my code.  I cannot find a setting in EPPlus that will handle this (If there is one, please make me aware of it). I am trying to figure out how to customize the XML directly but I'm having trouble with that as well.

Is there a way I can accomplish this?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with epplus sadly enough. What I do when I work with OOXML documents (only worked with Word so far though) is to put on the grid, like you want it, save it and search in the document how the element is specified. If you download Office Open SDK 2.5 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) you can take the download with the Tools. In the tools application you can open all ooxml documents and watch the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit strange that was not added since it is fairly easy to turn on.  Here is how to do it with XML (if you want to set color and size you have to get more into the XML manipulation but this will get you started):

```
using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
{
    var workbook = pck.Workbook;
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
    worksheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(datatable, true);

    var chart = worksheet.Drawings.AddChart("chart test", eChartType.XYScatter);
    var series = chart.Series.Add(worksheet.Cells["B2:B11"], worksheet.Cells["A2:A11"]);

    //Get reference to the worksheet xml for proper namespace
    var chartXml = chart.ChartXml;
    var nsuri = chartXml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI;
    var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(chartXml.NameTable);
    nsm.AddNamespace("c", nsuri);

    //XY Scatter plots have 2 value axis and no category
    var valAxisNodes = chartXml.SelectNodes("c:chartSpace/c:chart/c:plotArea/c:valAx", nsm);
    if (valAxisNodes != null && valAxisNodes.Count > 0)
        foreach (XmlNode valAxisNode in valAxisNodes)
        {
            if (valAxisNode.SelectSingleNode("c:majorGridlines", nsm) == null)
                valAxisNode.AppendChild(chartXml.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "c:majorGridlines", nsuri));
            if (valAxisNode.SelectSingleNode("c:minorGridlines", nsm) == null)
                valAxisNode.AppendChild(chartXml.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "c:minorGridlines", nsuri));
        }

    //Other charts can have a category axis
    var catAxisNodes = chartXml.SelectNodes("c:chartSpace/c:chart/c:plotArea/c:catAx", nsm);
    if (catAxisNodes != null && catAxisNodes.Count > 0)
        foreach (XmlNode catAxisNode in catAxisNodes)
        {
            if (catAxisNode.SelectSingleNode("c:majorGridlines", nsm) == null)
                catAxisNode.AppendChild(chartXml.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "c:majorGridlines", nsuri));
            if (catAxisNode.SelectSingleNode("c:minorGridlines", nsm) == null)
                catAxisNode.AppendChild(chartXml.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "c:minorGridlines", nsuri));
        }

    pck.Save();
}
```

Comment: The line `catAxisNode = chartXml.SelectSingleNode("c:chartSpace/c:chart/c:plotArea/c:catAx", nsm); ` Did not work.  This is because "c:catAx" did not exist.  Instead there was a second "c:valAx" tag.  Therefore, I was able to correct the bug by replacing the line in question with: `var catAxisNode = valAxisNode.NextSibling;`.  With that minor correction, this code worked perfectly!  Thank you, I had been stuck on this for ages!

Comment: ah, I didn't see your edit when I wrote that comment.  Thanks!

Comment: @jnel899  Cool. Ya, I realized that would be a problem after I posted.  Just be careful using relative node searches with something like `NextSibling` since it is not guaranteed that they will be next to each other.  Glad you got it working.